# inject JS code into a textarea

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show some JS code in a textarea. The code is generated with JS so I am injecting it into the textarea with JS. However, using the `<script>` tags, causes the script to execute. I thought using `&lt;` would solve this, but this is simply displaying `&lt;` instead of `<`.

Any suggestions how I can do this?

```
$('myTextarea').set('value', '<script>alert('do something');</script>');
```

Comment: you should've used jquery tag

Comment: @Agent_L: Why should he?

Comment: @j08691 - jQuery does not have a `set()` function as far as I know. But the question is obviously missing vital information.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - yeah thanks I already caught that and fixed it before you posted your comment.

Comment: Which JavaScript library has a .set() method?

Answer (score 1):

Just separate the script tag into two.

```
$('myTextarea').val('<script>alert("do something");</scr'+'ipt>');
```

Comment: psst.. it's the `</script>` that needs escaping, not the `<script>` ;)

Comment: You need to escape the quotes around "do something" :-P

Comment: @Rocket why need to escape..?

Comment: @GabrielSantos: There were single quotes inside the single quotes.  It's fixed now :-)

Comment: @Rocket I have seen only the fixed version, sorry =D

Answer (score 0):

The next `</script>` after the opening `<script>` block closes the script block; whether it's contained with a JS string or not.

To fix you can either split the `</script>` like so;

```
$('myTextarea').set('value', '<script>alert('do something');</scr' + 'ipt>');
```

Or like this (less common, but works, and probably more *correct*);

```
$('myTextarea').set('value', '<script>alert('do something');<\/script>');
```

Furthermore, you also need to fix your quotes;

```
$('myTextarea').set('value', '<script>alert(\'do something\');<\/script>');
```

You can see this now working here: http://jsfiddle.net/pK9SK/